# NSScanner string always nil (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_i386_INVOP,subcode=0x0))

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsscanner

When using `NSScanner`, the following code:

```
var s: String?
var b: NSString?
let scn = NSScanner(string: "andgostring")
scn.scanUpToString("go", intoString: &b)
b = NSString(string:"http")
s = b // <--- Crashes here
```

...crashes with

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_i386_INVOP,subcode=0x0

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? The last line `s = b` does not compile with the current Xcode 6.3, and if I change it to `s = b as String?` then it does not crash at all.

Comment: I'm using XCode 6.2. I too noticed that casting to String doesn't crash.